# Problems importing an Android project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, workspace

I reinstalled my computer and tried now to import my Android project into the workspace.
(File -> Import -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace)

But now I have got a strange error.

```
    bNormal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gotoNextQuestion();
        }
    });
```

In the second line (@Override) eclipse always tells me there is an error:

```
/* Multiple markers at this line
- implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick
- The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass Method */
```

This happens everywhere, where @Override is used. 
I already tried to `Android-Tools -> Fix Project Settings` and `Project -> Clean`.

I hope somebody can help me with this strange problem.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is because the language level is set to 5.0. Change it to 6, and all will work fine. Don't know where to set it eclipse, but in Idea it's File - Project Structure - Project Language level

It happens because `OnClickListener` is an interface and in 5th Java `@Override` can not be applied to a method implementation.

Comment: You are right! I needed to change File -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> from 1.5 to 1.6

Answer (score -3):

Your android SDK is probably not in the same path. Fix that in your eclipse settings.